# Least square for complex exponential function

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, least-squares

**Real problem:** I have $n$ points $(t_i, \ x_i)$ (from an experiment) and I want to find the best values for $X = (A, B, \xi, \omega)$ to fit

$$
x(t) = \exp \left(-\xi \omega t\right)\left(A\cos \mu \omega t + B \sin \mu \omega t\right)
$$

With $0 < \xi < 1$ and $\mu = \sqrt{1-\xi^2}$.

My minimizing function $J$ (least square) is

$$
J(A, \ B, \xi, \ \omega) = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x(t_i) - x_i)^2
$$

Then, the equation to solve is

$$
\nabla J = \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial A} & \dfrac{\partial J}{\partial A} & \dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \xi} & \dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \omega}\end{bmatrix} = \vec{0}
$$

As it's not a linear equation, I use Newton's method

$$
X_{j+1} = X_{j} - \left[\nabla \nabla J\right]^{-1} \cdot \left[\nabla J\right]
$$

Unfortunately, this method converges only when I get a good estimative for a initial value $X_{0}$. And it's very bad cause my data is very noisy.

**Complex problem** So, I thought about transforming my equation into a complex to reduce the number of variables to $C, \ s \in \mathbb{C}$:

$$
s = -\xi \omega + i \cdot \mu \omega \in \mathbb{C}
$$

$$
C = A + i \cdot B \in \mathbb{C}
$$

$$
z(t) = C \exp \left(s t\right)
$$

And this equation is a lot easier to solve, cause I can separate and make a linear regression (least square) using the equation:

$$
\ln z = \ln C + s \cdot t
$$

And once found $z(t)$ I can get $x(t)$ like

$$
x(t) = \Re(z(t))
$$

Unfortunately I don't have the 'imaginary' points $y_i$ to put in $z_i = x_i + i \cdot y_i$ and compute the regression in the complex plane.

**Question:** Is there any possibility to make this work? I mean, transform a real problem (with 4 real variables) into a complex problem (with 2 complex variables) and get an method more stable (less dependent on $X_0$ or even get rid of it)?

**Context:** The function $x(t)$ is the solution for the ODE of a mass-spring-damper when $0 < \xi < 1$ and I got experimental data $(t_i, \ x_i)$ with noise. So I want the best values for $\xi$ and $\omega$ to characterize my system.

$$
m \ddot{x} + c\dot{x} + k x = 0
$$

$$
\ddot{x} + 2\xi \omega \dot{x} + \omega^2 x = 0
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with perfect data, a model such
$$x = \exp \left(-\xi \omega t\right)\left[A\cos (\mu \omega t )+ B \sin (\mu \omega t)\right]\qquad \text{with} \quad \mu = \sqrt{1-\xi^2}$$ would be very difficult to fit in the absence of good guesses.

Fortunately, there are only two parameters which make the problem nonlinear : $\xi$ and $\omega$.

For the time being, suppose that we fix their values. Defining two variables
$$y_i=\exp \left(-\xi \omega t_i\right)\cos (\mu \omega t )\qquad \text{and} \qquad z_i=\exp \left(-\xi \omega t_i\right)\sin (\mu \omega t )$$ the problem becomes

$$\Phi(A,B)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Big[A y_i+B z_i-  x_i\Big]^2$$ is more than simple to minimize using normal equations
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\,y_i=A \sum_{i=1}^{n} y^2_i+B\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i\,z_i$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\,z_i=A \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i\,z_i+B\sum_{i=1}^{n} z^2_i$$

from which the values of $A_{\text{opt}}$, $B_{\text{opt}}$ and $\Phi_{\text{min}}=\Phi(A_{\text{opt}},B_{\text{opt}})$ for the current $\xi$ and $\omega$.

Now, build a regular grid for $0 < \xi < 1$ and $0 <\omega < ?$ and for each pair compute $\Phi_{\text{min}}$ and search for the couple $(\xi,\omega)$ whic gives the lowest value of $\Phi_{\text{min}}$.

When found, you have your starting guesses for $(A,B,\xi,\omega)$ and you can start Newton-Raphson iterations.

Comment: Nice! I found out that using $omega_{x} = \xi \omega$ and $\omega_{d} = \mu \omega$ is easier in Newton's method, cause with $\xi$ sometimes I get out of the range $(0, \ 1)$. I can use a filter I get a good estimate of $\omega_{x}$ and $\omega_d$. Then my main problem became find the initial values of $A$ and $B$ cause, and your response is just what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: I've done a [Python notebook](https://github.com/carlos-adir/UnB-Courses/blob/main/vibracoes/estimate_parameters.ipynb) to find parameters from artificially noisy data.

Comment: @CarlosAdir. This is great !

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be written like:
$$x(t)=Ce^{-\xi\omega t}\cos(\mu\omega t+\phi)$$
where $C$ and $\phi$ depends on $A$ and $B$. It doesn't change anything but we can see things more clearly.

First, there is an oscillation pattern (the cosine function) and a decreasing pattern (the exponential). I would try first to find a way to identify the frequency of the oscillating behaviour ($\mu\omega$) and the decreasing characteristic time ($\xi\omega$).

My hunch is that, maybe if you can measure $\dot{x}(t)$ (the derivative of $x$) then the oscillating part, then the problem will become much simpler to solve?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a way to measure $\dot{x}$. I could do that by derivating my data (divided difference), but the noise makes it almost impossible to get any information from it.

Comment: Maybe if you can do a physical model, which takes into account the generating process, then fitting could become more natural. The way you have currently setup your problem is extremely dependent on the cosine frequency so it will not be stable. Maybe fitting that frequency first is the important thing to do.